# Should we get rid of deadlocks with anyother else program which not being developed by us?

Tags: deadlock

Suppose the below two source code are developed by different developers and they do not know each other. Does each one has to take the responsibility about his own program's deadlock issue while his does not know there is another program would have deadlock with his?

https://gist.github.com/changyuheng/6820188
※Note: Can be compiled by GCC with -std=gnu99

Comment: Yes, the international programming law forces them to handle possible dead lock situations.

Comment: Thank you! That is just what I want to know.

Comment: I hope you understood that I was sarcastic. There is no rules to what somebodies random code has to be able to do.

Comment: While the O.S. not handling the deadlock issue globally, we should consider any possible blocking condition as part of the flow?